# Prove that $f$ is an isomorphism, where the domain $Z$ is the group under normal addition and $G$ is the group from $Part (a).$

Tags: group-theory

Define $f∶\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow G$ by $f(x) = x−1$.

This is the group from part $a:$ Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and define $a \cdot b=a+b+1.$ We are assuming that $(G,\cdot)$ is a group.

For the proof that $f$ is a homomorphism, I have: $f(a+b)=a+b-1=(a-1)+(b-1)+1= f(a) \cdot f(b).$ Just want to make sure the proof is right.

Comment: Your proof that $f$ is a homomorphism is correct (I'm assuming that you're consciously ommiting quantifiers and would be able to write down a complete proof).

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is straight forward to check that you have an isomorphism.  The identity element of $G$ is $-1$, and the generators are $0$ and $-2$.

Comment: Could I also say that : Suppose $f(x)=1.$ Then $x-1=1$ which equals $0=e_{(Z,+)}.$ And that shows injective?

Comment: You need to show the kernel is zero.  The kernel is $\{x: f(x)=0\}$.  If you have already shown that $G$ is a group, whose identity is $-1$, then $\{x:f(x)=-1\} is now the kernel.  So take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it seems alright. And the map is a bijection from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$ . So, it's an isomorphism.